# Cryptographic Exception - Bad Data

Tags: c#, exception, encryption, cryptography

This is windows forms project. I have problem with decrypting an encrypted file. It throws me an exception:

- CryptographicException
- Additional information: Bad Data.

Here is the image link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2Y4w.png

Here is code needed for decryption:

```
DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

OpenFileDialog ofd2 = new OpenFileDialog();

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ofd2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        richTextBox4.Text = ofd2.SafeFileName;
    }
} private void richTextBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){}

public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
}

private void dec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pathK = ofd2.FileName;

    if (File.Exists(pathK))
    {
        string dirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(ofd2.FileName);
        string pathH = dirPath + "/DE" + ofd2.SafeFileName;

        if (File.Exists(pathH))
        {
            using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream(pathK, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(filestream, des.CreateDecryptor(des.Key, des.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (FileStream fsDecrypted = new FileStream(pathH, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        CopyStream(stream, fsDecrypted);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream(pathK, FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(filestream, des.CreateDecryptor(des.Key, des.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (FileStream fsDecrypted = new FileStream(pathH, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write)) 
                    {
                        CopyStream(stream, fsDecrypted);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        decTextBox.Text = "Cannot find encrypted file !";
    }          
} private void decTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){}
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading your code it looks like you're instantiating a new instance of `var des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider()` which generates a random Key and IV and trying to pass the randomly generated des.Key and des.IV to the CryptoStream. The problem is that the Key and IV are randomly generated given the constructor you're using. You need to use the matching Key and IV that was used to encrypt the bytes.

So at some point you should have code like:

```
des.Key = theKeyUsedToEncrypt;
des.IV = theIVUsedToEncrypt;
```

You're getting the bad data exception because decryption is failing because the randomly generated Key and IV does not match the one used to Encrypt.